# Convergence of Fourier series at discontinuities

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For the Fourier series in this question:
[Math Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfKRW.png)

How do I find out where the Fourier series converges, I initially thought I just apply this equation:  $ f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left\{f\left(x+\right)+f\left(x-\right)\right\}$ at points of discontinuity

From the graph I thought the only point of discontinuity is at $x=2$ and the Fourier series converges to 3/2 at $x=2$.

But the answer says it also converges to -1/2 at $x=4$. I'm not sure why it does this at $x=4$

Comment: $f$ is discontinuous at $x=4$, since the limit from the left is equal to $-1$ and the limit from the right is equal to $0$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Would this mean there is a discontinuity at $x=0$ also as the limits are different at that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function f(x) can be evaluated as defined in formula (1) below.

---

**(1)** $\quad f(x)=
 \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & 0\leq x<2 \\
 3-x & 2\leq x<4 \\
 f((x \bmod 4)) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.$

---

The following figure illustrates the function $f(x)$ defined in formula (1) above has discontinuities at $(x \bmod 4)=0$ as well as $(x \bmod 4)=2$. The jump at $(x \bmod 4)=0$ is from $-1$ to $0$ so the half-step at $(x \bmod 4)=0$ evaluates to $-\frac{1}{2}$ which is illustrated by the red dots in Figure (1) below. The jump at $(x \bmod 4)=2$ is from $2$ to $1$ so the half-step at $(x \bmod 4)=2$ evaluates to $\frac{3}{2}$ which is illustrated by the green dots in Figure (1) below.

---

[image: Illustration of f(x) defined in formula (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $f(x)$ defined in formula (1)